# How can i save my audio blob in file system

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm using jquery.voice.min.js and recorderWorker.js/recorder.js for to record audio with html5. At the moment I get to record audio and i get to url download html5 audio.

I want to save blob/audio html5 in my file system, but i dont know how.

When I get the url with audio i use this c How to ode, but i dont want to donwload audio, only want to save that blob audio in file system. How I can treat blob file for it?

```
$.voice.export(function(url){
 console.log(url); // blob:http://vshaker.com/934a8934-e11a-4049-b133-fcec8e240b29 
}, "URL");
```

Any clue, any idea?
Regards!

Comment: Local storage tends to be limited in size (5mb ish? can't find a reference) so this is unlikely to work well.

You might be able to look in to using the HTML5 AppCache or File system API.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the URL with base64 and you will get a base64 string of the corresponding audio.

```
    $.voice.export(function(url){
    console.log(url); // blob:http://vshaker.com/934a8934-e11a-4049-b133-fcec8e240b29 
    }, "base64");
```

post the base64data to server.
create the audio file using any of the server side language and keep any where in the file system. update the new web path to the audio source.

Comment: I am looking to save in local file system. How can I do this, instead of posting to server?